# Desk name plate for a PhD holder

Tags: vocabulary, honorifics

I have read the full article in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_%28title%29) and this [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23733/when-is-it-appropriate-to-refer-to-someone-as-dr-surname), but I am still unclear about this, as I am not a native speaker. A quick Google search did not help either. My brother recently received a PhD diploma in Chemistry. I would like to give him a desk name plate as a gift with a small insignia and his name and title. Should it be:

> Alexander Doe, PhD

or

> Doe Alexander, PhD

or something else? Is it appropriate to use Alex instead of Alexander?

In all likelihood, he is going to work in the U.K.

Comment: Consider the Finnish PhD hat and sword instead: https://www.jyu.fi/en/academic-events/degrees-ceremony/instruct/doctoral-hats-and-sword A nice little sword holder, with his name on it, at the front of the desk would look great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most desk nameplates tend to be firstname-surname.

This would be best, and avoid confusion:

> Alexander Doe, PhD

[Example on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001K35ISU)

Comment: +1, worth noting this is highly subject to cultural norms.  There are cultures that place the surname first … but, the UK would be: first last, degree.

Comment: Thank you for very much for your answer. This clears the matter for me. I cannot upvote due to low rep. I will do so when possible!

Comment: As @DavidM points out, there are different norms. For example, the same person could be Teresa Teng, PhD or Deng Lijun, PhD depending on whether they're following English or Asian tradition.